# How can I calculate $\mu_x/\mu_y$ using Jackknife?

Tags: confidence-interval, nonparametric, ratio, jackknife

I have difficulties in calculating confidence interval using Jackknife.
Suppose that I have two independent samples and I do not know both their population distributions.

I understand how to calculate the confidence interval of $\mu_x-\mu_y$, but I have no idea of how to calculate the confidence interval of $\mu_x/\mu_y$.

I think applying delta method is invalid since I can not guarantee that the two samples are from normal distribution.

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_estimator#Jackknife_estimation) might help you.

Comment: You should note that $\mu_x$-$\mu_y$ looks different from $\mu_x-\mu_y,$ and the latter is the proper way to do it. Just type a dollar sign and then don't type another until you get all the way through the mathematical notation that you're typing.